# Restrict search result to current site/web

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

My requirement is to search within sub site, if i am searching within a specific sub site result should come from current sub site. Here everything is working fine. But when I do advanced search it gives result from all site scope.

I can not create scope because we have more then 1000 sub site under one site collection and we have more then 50 site collections.

While I was looking at advanced search web part I don't see option for "Default to contextual scope" simile to search box web part.

I tried to set scope property of core result web part to "This Site" but its not working.

Note: I am not using FAST search

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the context url parameter **u** as query string. Example:

```
http://melcher.it/search/results.aspx?**k**=SharePoint&**cs**=This%20List&**u**=http://melcher.it/sharepoint/lists/projects
```

k = keyword
cs = contextual scope
u = contextual scope url

Here is an example how you can do something similar with JavaScript: http://joshmccarty.com/2011/05/sharepoint-contextual-search-updated/

Answer (score 1):

I'm using KeywordQuery to Search. Add each column you want returned to the "SelectProperties".

```
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(site);

keywordQuery.QueryText = "Search Term";
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("Title");
```

Comment: could you please add more details about it.